# How do I call a class after I've changed its name?

Tags: python, class, pickle

```
    newclassname = input("Name: ")
    class o:
        elements = [open_bases, open_addons01, open_addons02, open_releases01]
    o.__name__ = newclassname
    createdclasses.append(newclassname)
    print (createdclasses[0].elements)
    pickle_out = open("spl().pickle", "wb")
    pickle.dump(createdclasses, pickle_out)
    pickle_out.close()
```

The code which creates a class, adds pickled-in elements into it, then the class name is changed to one which the user chose. After that, I have no clue how to call the class.
When calling elements from newclassname, I get

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'elements'
```

However when calling it via the previous class name "o", I get an error which says "o" cannot be pickled.

Comment: why are you changing `o.__name__`??? `newclassname` is a `str` object. You call it the way you always called it, by using `o()`. Or if you want it assigned to another variable, do `Foo = o` and you can use `Foo()`, for example.

Comment: The player will define the name of that class. It is because that function will be ran multiple times, each time a new name for the class has to be given so it wouldn't overwrite the last one.